# Events wont fire on button click

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I made a site for a project, to which you can sign up. It'S hooked to a SQL database.

I'm trying to make a page in which admins can see info about different existing users, as well as delete some of them.

Issue is, the ban system works like that:
All users have a separate ban button who's ID is that of the Username, then, if an admin wants to ban a user, he clicks on the ban button next to the username, then an event is fired, and the ID of the button that the user clicked (which, as I said, equals to the username) is sent with a query and every user with that username gets deleted.

The event won't fire when I click one of the buttons generated by the code behind, but if I set up a button in the HTML aspx page with the exact same properties it works perfectly.

This is my code behind:

```
{
    public DbConnector Dbconnector = new DbConnector();

    public string htmllist = "";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null) Server.Transfer("logincode.aspx");
        if (Session["admin"] == null)
        {
            Server.Transfer("HomePage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            DbConnector dbc = new DbConnector();
            SqlDataReader reader = dbc.read("SELECT * FROM UsersTable ORDER BY id");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                htmllist += $"<tr><td class=\"id\">{reader["Id"].ToString()}</td>";
                htmllist += $"<td>{reader["Username"].ToString()}</td>";
                htmllist += $"<td>{reader["Password"].ToString()}</td>";
                htmllist += $"<td class = \"mail\">{reader["Email"].ToString()}</td>";
                htmllist += $"<td>{reader["IsAdmin"].ToString()}</td>";
                htmllist += $"<td><asp:Button runat=\"server\" name=\"{reader["Username"].ToString()}\" id=\"{reader["Username"].ToString()}\" class=\"btn\" value=\"Remove User\" OnClick=\"BanUser\"/></td></tr>";
                htmllist += "<br />";
            }
            dbc.closeconnection();
        }
    }
    protected void BanUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        string buttonid = button.ID;
        string banquery = $"DELETE FROM UsersTable WHERE Username = '{buttonid}';";
        new DbConnector().ExecuteCRUDQuery(banquery);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours but to no avail. 
Anyone knows what I did wrong?

**EDIT**

I wanted to mention that I've used inspect element to make sure that the button IDs are set correctly and they are. It's something about firing the event that's not working.

Comment: If you want to display data in tabular structure it's best to use gridview. That will also support showing controls such as buttons on each row and firing common event for all of them. They way you are creating buttons, they are actually not created as button controls and added to the page controls collection. This will not work for sure

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/rowcommand-event-in-gridview/

Comment: It's not about firing the event. You are trying to render an ASP button dynamically, but you cannot do that in the way you're doing it as a string. How are you rendering the string `htmllist`? You need to create a button in code (not string) and add it to the page. You need a container (e.g. placeholder) to add your button to, so you can control where it is added on the page. Otherwise you can add it directly to the page if you like.

Answer (score 0):

1- Ban a user is not equal to delete that user from DB , so consider that you may want to undo in the future .
2- You are using string datatype for an id . Id is always numeric .
3- It is so much easier to fire your event by Javascript or JQuery . why don't you use them ?
4- at your query you're setting the condition

```
WHERE Username = '{buttonid}'
```

you're equaling username to id , shouldn't be

```
WHERE Id = '{buttonid}'
```

?